# Why isn't AJAX working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to perform a simple ajax call to a simple php script to test that ajax is working.

HTML:

```
<button id="hi">hi</button>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#hi" ).click(function(){
   var dataString = "hi";
   $.ajax({
     url: "custom_scripts/hi.php",
     type: "POST",
     dataType:'json',
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){
       if(data.auth==true){
         alert("success: " + data.auth);
       }         
     }
   })
```

});

PHP:

```
<?php

    $hi=$_POST['hi'];

    $rVal=array("auth" => false);

    if(isset($hi)){
        $rVal['auth']=true;
    } else {
        $rVal['auth']=false;
    }

    echo json_encode($rVal);

?>
```

Are there any other scripts or libraries (from any language) that can interfere with ajax calls? When I step through, it's reaching the call, it's not returning any data (and no error in console) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass Ajax data as:

```
 data: "hi="+dataString,
```

**Complete Ajax Example:**

```
$( "#hi" ).click(function(){
   var dataString = "hi";
   $.ajax({
     url: "custom_scripts/hi.php",
     type: "POST",
     dataType:'json',
     data: "hi="+dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){
       if(data.auth==true){
         alert("success: " + data.auth);
       }         
     }
   }) 
});
```

In your example, if you check browser console, you are getting `Undefined Index Notice`.